# How to see if the process was killed?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, timeout

When you want to set a time limit for a process, you can simply use `timeout` before the process:

```
timeout 1.5s COMMAND
```

This will kill the `COMMAND` if it was not done after 1.5 seconds.

I used that command in some bash scripts; How can i know if one process was completely done before the time limit, or it was killed (because of exceeding the time limit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gnu `timeout` command normally returns a status code of 124 if the timeout was exceeded. Otherwise, it returns the status code returned by the command itself. So you can test the status code by grabbing the value of `$?` immediately after executing `timeout`:

```
timeout 1.5s COMMAND
status=$?
if ((status==124)); then
  # command timed out
elif (status!=0)); then
  # command terminated in time, but it returned an error status
else
  # command terminated in time and reported success
fi
```

If your command might return the status code 124, then you would have to use the `--preserve-status` option and check to see if the command was terminated by the signal you tell `timeout` to send. See the [`man timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Add `&& echo >> time_limit.txt` after `COMMAND`:

```
timeout 1.5s COMMAND && echo >> time_limit.txt
```

So, if you want to see if the `COMMAND` was killed, check the existence of file `time_limit.txt`. If that file exists, it means the command was NOT killed. Otherwise, the command was killed.

In bash script, you can check the existence of that file as follow:

```
if [[ -r time_limit.txt ]]then;
{
    echo "The command was NOT killed"
}
else
{
    echo "The command was killed"
}
```